# Sort 2 Activerecords by date - when date fields are a different name in RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, date, activerecord

this is my first post here (first time I couldn't find an answer!)

I have 2 Records

```
Course.spotlight
NewsItem.spotlight
```

Both return 5 records. I have combined them with:

```
@spotlight = Course.spotlight + NewsItem.spotlight
```

`Course.spotlight` is sorted by `release_date` and 
`NewsItem.spotlight` is sorted by `publish_at` and both are date fields.

My question is how do i (now that they are combined) sort them by date when the date fields are different names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Ruby method `sort_by`:

```
@spotlight = @spotlight.sort_by do |record|
  if record.respond_to?(:release_date)
    record.release_date
  else
    record.publish_at
  end
end
# sort by date ASC, you can use reverse! to change to order to DESC
# @sportlight.reverse!
```

This code implies that every `@spotlight` records will always return a date from calling either `release_date` or `publish_at` (Ruby can't compare nil with Date). Also, this could be expensive in performances if you have a lot of records in `@spotlight` (like a hundred of records or more).

Comment: This sorts them - but sorts them in batches - first i get sorted Courses then sorted NewsItems. I don't get the mixed content I'm looking for currently

Comment: What do you mean by that? Can you give an example of the output?

Comment: So I get Course 1 - Course 2 - Course 3 - NewsItem 1 - NewsItem 2 - NewsItem 3.     I am expecting However, Course 1 - NewsItem1, Course 2, NewsItem 2, Course 3, NewsItem 3

Comment: seems to be sorting by asc. is there an easy way to desc this?

Comment: Use a `.reverse` after the `sort_by` call and you're good to go ;-)